# 3 High School Precalculus Word Problems Help/Check

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> 1.) The formula for calculating the distance traveled for a given time is $D(t)=v_it+0.5at^2$, where $v_i$ is the initial velocity and a is the acceleration. A car is moving at $12\ \mathrm{m/s}$ and coasts up a hill with an acceleration of $-1.6 \ \mathrm{m/s^2}$.
>
> a.) Explain what negative acceleration is.

I am not sure exactly what it is, but is it when a car just slows down?

> b.) For what values of $t$ does $D(t)=43$?

I think the answer is $5.9$ and $9.8$ seconds when solving with the quadratic formula.

> c.) Explain why there are two times for the same distance.

I have absolutely no clue about this. I know the shape is a parabola so it would have two times, but why?

> 2.) Make a conjecture about the $x$-intercept of $y=(ax+b)^n$ if $y=x^n$ is the parents function.

I think they would have the same $x$-intercepts. Is there something else that can be determined too like the amount of $x$-int? Is there a formula to find the amount like $n-1$?

> 3.) Suppose the graph $g(x)$ has two relative maxima and one relative minimum.
>
> a.) What is the minimums degree of $g(x)$?

Is the minimum degree $4$ because it has $4$ $x$-intercepts?

Comment: Kindly use Mathjax. Avoid including "I have no clue" in your questions. Here's some suggestions for asking a good question: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. As this question appears to be homework, please consider reading [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803) for information about asking _effective_ homework-related questions. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

First, forget about the math and just use your intuition.  If you launch a car up a hill with some amount of speed, what is it going to do?  It's going to roll up, slow down, stop, then start sliding back down to the bottom.

Now let's add the math back in.  $D(t)$ is the distance from some spot (presumably the bottom), that the car is located.

a) Positive acceleration is acceleration in the positive direction.  What's the positive direction?  Usually it is up by convention.  So negative acceleration is acceleration in the negative direction, i.e. down.  So gravity will create a negative acceleration because it will cause acceleration in the negative direction.  The positive or negative of acceleration is telling you which way the thing (car in this case) is accelerating.

So if a car is moving in the positive direction and experiences negative acceleration, then it will cause the car to slow down.  Initially.  The it will stop, and then start traveling faster and faster in the negative direction.

b) So $D(t)=43$ is just asking at what time is the distance of the car $43$ (meters, I guess, since the other units are mks).  Again, imagine the car going up the hill, and then back down.  They want to know when that happens.  I am not checking your math, but using the quadratic formula is a good approach.  You can check it by plugging in $5.9$ and, separately, $9.8$ into $D(t)$ and make sure you get $43$.

c) So mathematically, you are right.  A parabola can have two solutions (or $1$ or $0$).  But intuitively, think again about the car going up the hill.  It slows down, stops, then rolls backwards.  If you were to stand at $43$ $\mathrm{m}$ and the car goes by you once, you would expect it to roll back again in a little bit!

2) I would disagree with your conjecture.  What is an $x$-intercept?  It is located at the places where $y=0$.  I would think it would be where $ax+b=0$....

3) I'm assuming you are paraphrasing, or that the context is polynomials.  There are many curves/functions that don't have "degrees".  The maxima and minima don't tell you where the curve is relative the x-axis, which is what you would be relevant if we are talking about intercepts.  For example, you can have a quadratic with no intercepts ($y=x^2+1$).  So I don't think we want to think about intercepts of $g(x)$.

However, what does it tell us about the derivative of $g(x)$ that we have $3$ relative maximia/minima?  It tells us that the derivative has $3$ $x$-intecepts.  Now if the derivative has $3$ intercepts, than it must by at least a cubic polynomial.  If the derivative is at least an order $3$ polynomial, then $g(x)$ must be ....

Comment: For 2.) if n was the same value as each other, wouldn't they have the same x-intercepts though? And for 3.) do you think g(x) would have a degree of 3 then? I thought only degrees of 3 would have 2 max/mins. A degree of 4 could have 2 max and 1 min.